# Security implications of putting SElinux in permissive mode on Android kitkat (CM 11.0)

Tags: android, selinux

Cyanogenmod 11.0 now has SELinux enabled, but you can change it to permissive mode with an app in the app store (SElinux Mode Changer).  Doesn't this defeat the purpose of SELinux?  Anything one app can do, another app can do maliciously, right?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why rooting a device is considered to be weakening its security. You need root privileges to change this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the device is rooted, switching between enforcing and permissive modes is only possible in kernels that were built with `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y` in the defconfig. For a secure production device, this should be disabled as it greatly reduces the negative impacts of deliberate rooting or a vulnerability that yields root privileges.

When SELinux Development mode is enabled, you need to be root to run `setenforce` (assuming `sepolicy` allows it, which it usually does, but not necessarily):

```
usage:  setenforce [ Enforcing | Permissive | 1 | 0 ]
```

SELinux Mode Changer requires a rooted device, which means it works by getting root and calling `setenforce 0`.  As you pointed out, this pretty much defeats the whole purpose of SELinux, and that's precisely why rooting is not a good idea unless you can accept all of the risks.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel is not built with CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y, it doesn't matter whether you root the phone or not.  In that case SELINUX policy will not permit you to execute the setenforce command, even if you are root.  So it really makes no sense that Google Play has disallowed the SElinux Mode Changer app.  What that app can do, any app can do.  Removing it from Google Play is akin to security by obscurity.  The CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y opens a security hole by adjusting SELinux policy to permit changing the SELinux mode through setenforce.  That's useful for development but defeats the purpose of SElinux in real use.